# How many pets do we know about on the Enterprise-D?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, animals, uss-enterprise

Obviously Data has his cat Spot and Picard has his fish.  Bit of a random question, but **what other pets do we know that reside on the Enterprise-D** i.e. how many do we know about?

Comment: I've often wondered how many pets are on the Enterprise-D. +1!

Comment: @Praxis Like I say, a bit of a random question, but glad you liked it!  If you can find any more information, please feel free, mine is not exactly an exhaustive list!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We know about :

- [Christina](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Christina), O'Brien's tarantula (TNG: *Realm of Fear*)
- [Livingston](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Livingston), Picard's Lionfish
- The two [Spots](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Spot), Data's cats (kudos Xantec)
- Amanda Rogers' three dogs for a brief period (TNG: *True Q*) (Kudos Xantec)
- Worf's Targ for a few seconds (TNG: *Where No One Has Gone Before*) (Kudos Xantec again!)
- Tasha Yar's cat for a few seconds (TNG: *Where No One Has Gone Before*) (Kudos Xantec)

We also know that there are other cats:

> BARCLAY: I'm curious, sir. Who's the father?
>
> DATA: I am not certain.
>   Spot has escaped from my quarters on several occasions and there are
>   **twelve male felines on board**. I intend to run a full DNA analysis on
>   the kittens once they

(TNG: [*Genesis*](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/271.htm))

It seems there may have been at least one male and one female dog as well:

> In early 2365, a litter of puppies visited the nursery aboard the
>   Enterprise-D. Ian Troi was among the children who played with the
>   puppies. (TNG: "The Child")

([Source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dog))

For a short time, the being in the form of the dog [Maura](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Maura) was on the ship, but didn't 'reside' on the *Enterprise-D* per-se.

So, there's at least 24 pets on board that we have seen, including those that were there for a brief period of time (not counting the puppies), but there were probably many more that we didn't see.

---

Not on the *Enterprise-D*, but just a fun fact, Dr Zimmerman's holographic lizard was called [Leonard](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Leonard)

Comment: _Technically_, Maura was never on the ship... in fact, _Maura_ was never seen on screen.

Comment: @T.J.L., well, if you want to be *technical* about it, then there was a being in the form of a dog that was on the *Enterprise*, but I guess you're right

Comment: Amanda Roger's dogs were on the Enterprise for a few seconds. Also, Data has had at least two cats named Spot, one male and one female. As for the puppies, we don't know that they were born from dogs on the ship; they could have been picked up before or during the episode. In the same episode with Amanda Rogers *Q* turned Beverly Crusher into a dog for a few seconds, although I don't believe anyone would have claimed her as a pet.

Comment: I think it is the first episode with the Traveler when Worf's pet Targ appears on the bridge for a couple seconds. Tasha Yar's pet cat may have also made an appearance on the Enterprise in this episode, but perhaps not.

Comment: Would Lwaxana's living vine-thing from "Haven" count?  The one that terrified Deanna's mother-in-law-to-be?

Comment: @PaulL as Lwaxana (and therefore likely her vine pet) doesn't *reside* on the Enterprise, I don't think it would count

Comment: @OftenRight Amanda Rogers was an extremely temporary visitor (and her dogs even more so), yet you included them in your answer... :-)

Comment: @PaulL true - in that case I should remove her dogs from the list!

Comment: Doesn't Q refer to Worf as Picard's pet?

Comment: Another source: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_pets