# Are there insects aboard the Enterprise-D?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I noticed one scene in ST:TNG where a fly can be seen flying near Data's head during a close-up. It somehow seemed wrong to me (it bugged me, you might say). Apparently the director didn't think it was a problem and kept it in (didn't do a re-take).

Are there bugs on Federation Starships? Has this ever been addressed? Somehow I find it hard to believe they still have pest problems in the 24th century.

Comment: do nanites count? ;) Also - assuming you mean 'bugs' in the form of actual, loose pests, not in the context of the school 'zoo' that we see the school children visit

Comment: Obviously there are if you invite them to dinner; http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Jarada

Comment: “Apparently the director didn't think it was a problem” — TVs only show 640 × 480 pixels! They’ll never see it!

Comment: What episode is this?

Comment: The USS Enterprise is the flagship - it would not do to have insects about, chewing on starship cabling or isolinear chips....I bet the sensors scan for them and then, in true federation style, beam them into a humane environment.

Comment: @PhasedOut Do you mean, like, oh, I don't know, a Klingon Cruiser?

Comment: They didn't mind kids running around causing a raucous though.

Comment: (outside of the J.J. Abrams universe) Starships are built in space and very few have the ability to land. The only chance an insect would have to board the ship is via shuttlecraft or on the rare occasion when one is missed by the transporter biofilter as seen in the voyager episode "macrocosm."

Comment: @Z.Cochrane I noticed it in Data's Day when Data is telling Troi that he can't grow old together with a mate because he doesn't age. freetrek also noticed one in the same episode when he's feeding Spot. Apparently there were lots of flies around when they shot Data's Day.

Comment: There is an interesting [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyD6sZZ-QWs) about things that were accidentally captured in-frame, and how they would have gone un-noticed in the days of limited-resolution analog TV when clear freeze-frames were a rarity. Enterprise D gives an impression of "everything in its place", so loose pests (bugs) would not be a thing... any insects aboard ship would be suitably contained either for display or study.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### The Enterprise is free of insects.

> **DATA:** *I have been watching Spot sleep. In the past fifteen minutes, he has had twelve muscles spasms, which indicates he was
> dreaming. I have often wondered what Spot dreams about. His twitching
> and his rapid breathing would seem to suggest anxiety, but Spot has
> never seen a mouse or any other form of rodentia. **He has never
> encountered an insect**, or been chased by a canine.*
>
> <sup>**[TNG: Phantasms](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/258.htm)**</sup>

**Except those that are kept as pets, obviously**

> **TROI:** *Welcome home, Worf. I hope you don't mind, I let myself in. I promised Alexander I'd feed his **Dalvin hissing beetle** while you were both away.*
>
> <sup>**[TNG: Parallels](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/263.htm)**</sup>

Comment: another pet: while not "technically" an insect - O'Brian has a pet spider

Comment: Don't forget that the Enterprise is primarily an exploration vessel, with a fair number of scientists aboard. It's highly likely that there would be some sort of entomology lab on board.

Comment: @NKCampbell - Spiders are not insects. I remember that much from school at least.

Comment: that's why I said 'not technically' but they are often lumped together by people when speaking of 'bugs'

Comment: @Irishpanda I'm only asking about loose insects (like the one seen near Data's head), as Valorum correctly noted in his answer.

Comment: @NKCampbell you're correct my question would apply to loose spiders as well. But don't even THINK of giving Barclay in "Genesis" as an answer!

Comment: The Enterprise did have an [arboretum](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Arboretum), they might have had insects in that section since some plants need them for pollination (and if any of the plants were transplants rather than ones grown from seeds, it's possible some insects would have hitched a ride)--maybe Data was just assuming that none had made it out into other sections where Spot might go. Another in-universe explanation could be that if a shuttlecraft was taken to a planet with life, an insect could have flown in and later flown out into the hangar bay.

Comment: @Woody : He really knows his Star Trek but I'd say he knows his CTRL+F even better.  ;-)  (Valorum knows I mean this in the most complimentary possible way.  The first thing one ought to do with a question of this type is search Chakoteya.net and/or official scripts.)

Comment: @Praxis - In this instance, I used Memory Alpha's pages on insects, insectoids and pets.

Comment: Perhaps that simply means that there are no insects in Data's quarters.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon - Given Spot's propensity for escaping, he's unlikely to just be referring to his own quarters

Comment: I found that segment from Phantasms really interesting. Seriously, what _does_ Spot dream about?!

Comment: The ship is huge, Richard! Has Spot been in even 1% of it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Given that she escapes (a lot), probably chasing other cats.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon - She's been on at least two decks, and probably more. That represents around 4.5% of the the ship right there.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon: I hope so! Even an unfeeling monster like Data couldn't possibly be cruel enough to confine that creature to quarters for his/her entire life, surely?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - That was his plan. Unfortunately (for Data), she would escape periodically. She also got herself pregnant.

Comment: @Valorum: The pregnancy was a bit of a shock, true, but it coming right on the heels of a spontaneous gender reassignment was even more impressive. Perhaps this cat is not _quite_ what we would call a "cat" today, which may also explain the dreams.

Comment: Did Data make that comment before or after there was a fly buzzing around his head?

Comment: That quote doesn't show that the Enterprise was insect-free. It only shows that Data's cat never happened to encounter one.

Comment: (Also, even just speaking about the places Spot has been, Data can't actually know that Spot has never encountered an insect, unless you are also claiming in this answer that there is implied canonical evidence that Data monitors and reviews all of Spot's activities at all times. That's not inconceivable, but it's a necessary conclusion from this answer, and I can't recall any actual strong evidence of that outside of this quote.)

Comment: @JasonC - Bearing in mind that Data knows that Spot has escaped on at least one occasion, the only way he could know with certainty that she's never encountered an insect is if there are **no insects to encounter**.

Comment: @Valorum Or he was incorrect. By your logic this quote also means there were no dogs, [which is false](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/100617/23051), which takes certainty away from this quote.

Comment: @JasonC - The dogs you're referring to were not allowed to roam the ship freely. You would no more expect spot to encounter them than O'Brien's pet spider.

Comment: @Valorum I just searched all TNG series and movie scripts for "dog" and "canine" and do not see anything stating that dogs were not allowed to roam. If we *assume* that they weren't allowed (because that seems reasonable), then we should equally assume *cats* weren't allowed to roam freely. Yet we know that sometimes cats escaped anyways, so we can just as reasonably assume that sometimes people's dogs escaped as well. We simply don't know if there were insects on board the enterprise or not, and every path an argument based on the quote in this answer takes ends in a logical problem.

Comment: @JasonC - I think you're over-thinking it. Data is confident that Spot hasn't encountered an insect because there aren't any insects, not because he imagines that he's consistently monitored her location (which we know he's happy to admit that he hasn't).

Comment: @Valorum Then, we're right back to the dogs thing. :) Data is confident that Spot hasn't encountered a dog because _____? Something is wrong in his statement. The only ways to resolve these outside of "Data might not know" are weird: E.g. you'd have to claim that the rules for cats and dogs are different on the Enterprise, or that insects *may* exist but are not allowed to wander as a rule, and that all animals in the future follow all rules that humans set, etc. And even if you ignore all that, the bigger problem is this is still just about the places Spot has been, not the whole Enterprise.

Comment: @JasonC - Again, overthinking it. Yes, there may be free insects in the arboretum (no evidence) and in the shuttlebays (no evidence). Find evidence that there's insects roaming the ship, other than a production error and then feel free to come back to me.

Comment: @Valorum Well, not overthinking, just overdiscussing. I see Data's statement as a directorial ambiguity, just as much as the fly on his face is a production error. Find evidence that there's no insects roaming the ship, that's where the burden of proof is; the provided quote just isn't strong enough to show that. The answer is, objectively: indeterminate. There isn't good evidence either way. The quote you provided definitely suggests it's a possibility (it doesn't *rule out* that there are no insects), but also doesn't show it's true, not enough for a bold definitive header at least! :)

Answer (score 6):

Indeterminate. We don't know for sure.

To disagree with the "canonical" answer given above.

There is no evidence that there is absolutely no insects on the Enterprise. Spot no seeing insects is just Spot's experience, not a census study.

Just think what technology would be needed to control such small lifeforms in an absolute way. A new kind of insecticide? Even our best are not foolproof (think the fly on Data, which is visual proof). Also, some insects are the size of small grains, so you would need a technology that scans (all?) particles in a vessel, distinguishes the insects, and then takes (or assigns) actions. No such technology is evidenced in Star Trek, to my knowledge.

Comment: Between force-fields, transporter screening, sterile fields, internal scanners, electromagnetic barriers and pinpoint transporter technology, you'd expect the ship to be almost completely sterile.

Comment: When was the last time we saw anyone on Star Trek *cleaning* anything, on screen?

Comment: yeah i'd say the bio filters on the transporter probably keep them from inadvertently beaming any up... wouldn't want some disease carrying mosquito to start a problem any more than the bacteria itself

Comment: _"Also, some insects are the size of small grains, so you would need a technology that scans (all?) particles in a vessel, distinguishes the insects, and then takes (or assigns) actions"_ They're pretty good at detecting viruses in the air. Those are a heck of a lot smaller than insects.

Comment: I disagree.  I think Data's confidence that Spot has never seen an insect despite not always being with him tells us that there are no stray insects aboard the Enterprise-D.

Comment: Given that the crew routinely fails to see giant alien growths, parasites, etc., I find it unlikely they would catch all the tiny bugs around. Especially considering there are bugs on the ship deliberately, a few of which would undoubtedly escape their habitats from time to time.

Comment: @SudoSedWinifred No. At best it merely implies that the limited places Spot has been, such as Data's quarters, are insect-free. At least as far as Data is aware.

Comment: @MichaelS Don't forget there is also the five year [Baryon Sweep](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Baryon_sweep). That would get rid of any unknown insect infestations.

Answer (score 5):

TNG S03E11 - (Data's Day) When Data feeds Spot feline supplement #74. Data sets the bowl on the floor and as soon as Spot starts eating the food.

Look closely and you will see a fruit type fly crawling inside the bowl from left to right in an upward direction.

[image]

Comment: A great find, and worthy of a bounty for having such good eyes.

Comment: That's the same episode I noticed the fly in - but a different scene!